# Invalid use of Me keyword

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This code is a function and not a private subroutine. I'm suddenly getting this error with the Me.[field name here]. I'm not getting that error in my other code, just in this one. Here's my full code without the boring end part, but I'm getting the error starting from the line:

`Me.assignedby.Column(1)`

```
Public Function AssignNullProjects() As Long

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    assignedby = TempVars("user").Value

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        While Not rs.EOF
            strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee & ", assignedby = " & Me.assignedby.Column(1) & ", Me.Dateassigned = #" & Now & "#, Me.actiondate = #" & Now & "#, Me.Workername = " & _
                              Me.assignedto.Column(0) & ", Me.WorkerID = " & Me.assignedto.Column(0) & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
```

What could be the possible reason for the above-stated error, and how it could be removed?

Comment: It looks like some of your Mes are in quotes. EDITED: They definitely are.

Comment: It's saying in general that the Me.[fieldname] is an invalid use of Me. which doesn't make sense because I literally use a similar code in another macro and it works fine. It's just not working here. Not sure it that is because this is a Public Function and not a Private Sub

Comment: Replace the UPDATE with this: "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee & ", assignedby = " & Me.assignedby.Column(1) & ", Dateassigned = #" & Now & "#, actiondate = #" & Now & "#, Workername = " & _
                              Me.assignedto.Column(0) & ", WorkerID = " & Me.assignedto.Column(0) & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I haven't done VB (or VBA) for many years but I think your problem is including Me in your hard coded parts (string literal) of the query.

Comment: No that didn't work. Still getting the same error. I'm getting the error right here: `" & Me.assignedby.Column(1) & "`

Comment: Column(1) is only seen once in your code above. Is it part of the string still? What is the actual error? What happens if you remove the Me keyword from before the assignedby.Column(1) part?

Comment: HansUp actually steered me in the right direction. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that code in the form's code module.  When you try to use `Me` in a standard module, you will always get that *"Invalid use of Me keyword"* complaint.

Check out the *"Invalid use of Me keyword"* and *"Me <keyword>"* topics in Access' help system for further details.

Comment: I totally forgot about modules and assumed you are in a form