# Get current record values

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors, record

I'm quite new at programming in Access VBA.

I have a form that shows one record at a time, and I added a button to run a code when you press it. In some part of the code, I need to get the values of the current record (shown in the form).

So, the form I'm working on is "frmProductos", and I want to assign the value of the field "fieldDescripcion" of the current record to 
"strDescripcion", which is a string type variable.

I tried the following code with no success: (something I found on the internet)

```
strDescripcion = Forms("frmProductos").CurrentRecord![fieldDescripcion]
```

but I get the Error message

> Compile error: Qualifier must be collection

I don't know if what I tried is close to the correct way to do it, if anyone could guide me I would be very grateful.

Comment: use _Me.FieldName_ instead if the button is in the Detail section.

Comment: Hi! couple of questions  - is the current record of the form displaying in a subform? Are there bound controls in the form that displays the record? Also, what logic is determing the "current record?"

Comment: @WLGfx When I try to use "Me"  I get the Compile Error _Invalid use of Me keyword_. I think I don't know when I can use it yet

Comment: @DougCoats Hmmm the current record is displayed in a Split Form. And the control is in the "subform" that displays one record at a time. (I dont know if that is called subform). With "current record" I mean the one that is being displayed above, in the Split Form

Comment: How is the code being called, event or something else. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062560/2979092

Comment: Try without the `CurrentRecord` - `strDescripcion = Forms.frmProductos![fieldDescripcion]`

Comment: Ahh, it's in a Public function in a Module. That's why _Me_ wasn't working. Thanks @WLGfx

Comment: @KostasK. I tried what you said and I get the Run-time error '424' _Object required_

Comment: KostasK had the right idea, but introduced a small error. Either use `Forms!frmProductos![fieldDescripcion]` or `Forms("frmProductos")![fieldDescripcion]`. If you need to use values that are only present in the underlying recordset, you can use `Forms!frmProductos.Recordset![fieldDescripcion]`

Comment: I know it's a bit late but I haven't been working these days. Thank you @ErikvonAsmuth!! It workeddd